# Edit the description box of Ant Design Basic Sunburst Plot

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to edit the description box of an Ant Design basic sunburst plot to include more information from my data. Being new to coding, I am struggling to use the website information, and have tried the following answer given to me by chat GPT but this hasn't worked:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Parent',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Child 1',
        value: 100,
        additionalValue: 20
      },
      {
        name: 'Child 2',
        value: 60,
        additionalValue: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Child 3',
        value: 30,
        additionalValue: 5
      }
    ]
  }
];

const tooltip = {
  formatter: (name, value, additionalValue) => {
    return `Name: ${name} <br/> Value: ${value} <br/> Additional Value: ${additionalValue}`;
  }
};

const config3 = {
  data: data,
  innerRadius: 0.3,
  tooltip: tooltip,
  interactions: [
    {
      type: 'element-active',
    },
  ],
}

const SunburstPlot = () => {
  return <Sunburst {...config3} />;
};
```

Ie nothing seems to turn up at all.

Is anyone able to suggest how I can get additional value to show up in my description box as well as my value?

Thanks!